# Refresh indicator-cpufreq

Tags: ati, cpufreq

Is there a way to refresh indicator-cpufreq / cpu frequencies after enabling a pstate on the cpu(without reboot)?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Kill the process and start it again:

```
user@host:~$ kill $(pidof indicator-cpufreq)
user@host:~$ indicator-cpufreq
```

Comment: Are you trying to kill indicator-cpufreq process using it's pid? Does it works?

Comment: @AvinashRaj yes, `pidof` gives the pid's of running processes and `kill` kills them with signal 15. You can also do `kill -9 $(pidof indicator-cpufreq)`.

Comment: `$ kill -9 $(pidof indicator-cpufreq)
kill: usage: kill [-s sigspec | -n signum | -sigspec] pid | jobspec ... or kill -l [sigspec]
`

Comment: Yeah, it's because there's no process called `indicator-cpufreq` running in your system, so `pidof indicator-cpufreq` stays empty and only `kill -9` is called without a <pid> and then `kill` complains. Try it with a process that exists.

Comment: no,`$ ps aux | grep indicator-cpufreq
avinash   2271  0.0  0.3 460240 27712 ?        Sl   09:37   0:14 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/indicator-cpufreq
avinash   3963  0.0  0.0  15944   924 pts/23   S+   19:44   0:00 grep --color=auto indicator-cpufreq
`

Comment: I think you can't kill an Sl process.

Comment: Why not? `S` means interruptible sleep and, `l` means multi-threaded. You can't kill a process in the state `D` (uninterruptible sleep) or `Z` (Zombie), but `S` is the normal sleep.